# Speed up indexing a column when rows > 5000

Tags: export, performance, import, large-lists

I've got a large list (>75,000 items, 41 columns) and therefore have to follow all the [rules for handling large lists](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-11ecc804-2284-4978-8273-4842471fafb7).

If a new column needs to be filtered on (and therefore needs to be indexed) then I'm force to export the list, delete rows until I'm < 5000 rows, add the index, and re-import the rows I deleted.  This process as currently done is very slow (days) because it is done with non-optimized CSOM code that copies to/from a SQL database.  An additional challenge is that the rules of large lists make it more difficult to write queries to identify 70K+ rows to use in the process.

My question is this:  How can I more quickly copy >70k rows to a temporary location, delete them, and then after indexing, moving the rows back to the original list?  Does Sharepoint support any form of quickly moving items to another table?  Are there any bulk import/export utilities for situations like this?

Comment: An farm administrator should be able to add an index regardless of how many items are in the list. Or the administrator can set a window of time daily during which large operations are allowed. So you could, for example, create a new index outside of normal business hours.

Comment: @Erin L Getting the farm administrators to make changes is also a cumbersome process.  If this can be done without them, it would be much better.

Comment: Then the second option I offered would be ideal. They only have to make the change once and then you'll have a window where you can do your own indexing.